# jQuery Function that fires when a select value has been changed?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Good day guys. So I'm trying to work on this simple jQuery program that triggers a function whenever and only whenever a select value has been changed. I plan to use this simple function in a more complex program once I make it work.

This is the code (it came from jQuery API website, and I modified it slightly to try what I wanted to happen):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>change demo</title>
    <style>
        div {
        color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="selector" name="sweets">
        <option>Chocolate</option>
        <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
        <option>Taffy</option>
        <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
        <option>Fudge</option>
        <option>Cookie</option>
    </select>
    <div></div>

    <script>
    $( "#selector" )
        .on('change',(function () {
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
                <?php header("Location:jcue.php")?>
            });
        })
        .change();
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to happen is that, the page should only redirect to jque.php once the select input value has been changed. But what's happening in the program is that it automatically redirects to another page without even loading the current page itself. What's the problem? jQuery and Javascript are the unexplored foreign lands for me in web programming, and I know this is pretty basic to many web programmers, but I just need it (and I really have to start learning Javascript, AJAX, and jQuery when I get to have free time haha).

The complex program I'm going to use it to is a search results filtering program. But before I can do that, I have to make this simple program work.

Can anybody help me? Thank you. Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as soon as browser looks at your php header, it will execute.

Comment: Why are you trying to do a redirect in a loop?

Comment: What is var str = "" for?

Comment: I see. So silly of me, already forgotten structural PHP. How do you suggest that I do this? Like for example, I need to go to a certain URL when the select value has been changed?

Comment: Disregard that var str. It's just a piece of code I forgot to remove when I was modifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead::

```
$(function() {
    $("#selector").change(function() {
        location.href = "jcue.php";
    });
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Pretty much solved my current dilemma. Can I use this in a little bit different way (CodeIgniter)? Like for example, go to a URL rather than a file?

Comment: Note: the `$(function() {})` construct is not necessarily required here as the script is at the end of the body.

Comment: @ChristianCastillo, yes you can use it CodeIgniter. Although in this case you will redirected to "juce.php" file via URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because your PHP gets executed as soon as the page loads - you cannot incorporate it as you have into javascript. Also, you don't need the `each()` within the handler. Try this instead:

```
$("#selector").on('change',(function () {
    window.location.assign('jcue.php');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is client-side script, while PHP is server-side. You are trying to trigger a PHP header redirect which should happen at server-time before it's sent to the client's browser. So this will not be working in that on change event.

Simply use:

```
$("#selector").change(function() {
    window.location = "jcue.php"; //this can be URL as well
});
```

P.S. I noticed you have two "selected" options, mind tell why?

Answer (score 0):

**Not so good practice:** to redirect using Javascript, since JS can be blocked

There were some syntax errors, here's a fix, just replace your code.

```
$( "#selector" ).on('change',(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    });
}));
```

**Good Practice:** use jquery ajax requests [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or redirect using standard [php header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function(which has to run before your html/js is loaded)

Good luck, learning programming. It's fun!